# Prepared statements with Postgrex & Ecto

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm trying to make use of postgres feature of returning pure json, so i have added a method to my Ecto model which executes a query, that returns the wanted json.

```
defmodule BoardApi.Board do
  use Ecto.Model

  def json_by_id(id) do
    sql = "SELECT row_to_json(json) AS result FROM (SELECT array_agg(users) AS users FROM users WHERE id=#{id}) json;"
    result = Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query(BoardApi.Repo, sql, [])

    return List.first(result.rows) |> Tuple.to_list |> List.first
  end
```

My problem, is that this has sql injection potential, is it possible to use something like prepared statements?

Comment: Quick advice: you can replace `... |> Tuple.to_list |> List.first` with `... |> elem(0)`.

Comment: Thank you @whatyouhide i was about to make a second question just for that :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [the documentation for `Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Adapters.SQL.html#query/4). The SQL statement can have numerical variables such as `$1`, `$2`, ..., and then those parameters are passed in a list using the third argument of the function call.

You can achieve what you want with:

```
defmodule BoardApi.Board do
  use Ecto.Model

  def json_by_id(id) do
    sql = "SELECT row_to_json(json) AS result FROM (SELECT array_agg(users) AS users FROM users WHERE id=$1) json;"
    result = Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query(BoardApi.Repo, sql, [id])

    # `return` is not valid Elixir
    result.rows |> hd |> elem(0)
  end
end
```